# Google BigQuery insert using POST

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to insert data to BigQuery table using POST request.
My application create body to request in specified format:

```
--xxx
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
   "configuration": {
       "load": {
           "sourceFormat": "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"
       },
       "destinationTable": {
           "projectId": "some-id",
           "datasetId": "dataset-id",
           "tableId": "cards"
       }
   }
}
--xxx
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

{"board_id":1,"version":2,"card_id":1,"title":"Tytul kartki 1"}
--xxx--
```

but when i send this data using:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        key,
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')
self.http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary=xxx'}
resp, content = self.http.request(url, method="POST",
                                       body=output,
                                       headers=headers)
```

the response from server is:

```
Status: {'date': 'Thu, 25 Jul 2013 12:49:06 GMT', 'status': '400', 'content-length': '205', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'server': 'HTTP Upload Server Built on Jul 12 2013 17:12:36 (1373674356)'}
Content: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter is missing"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter is missing"
 }
}
```

I have no idea what parameter is missing. Only parameter which is required in documentation is [sourceUris](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load.sourceUris) but i want to load data from request body not from GS.

Comment: I think you are missing setting the schema?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is you are missing the schema configuration:

```
'configuration': {
  'load': {
    'sourceFormat': <required for JSON files>',
    'schema': {
      'fields': [
        {'name':'f1', 'type':'STRING'},
        {'name':'f2', type:'INTEGER'}
      ]
    },
    'destinationTable': {
      'projectId': 'projectId',
      'datasetId': 'datasetId',
      'tableId': 'tableId'
    }
  }
}
```

This link maybe help you: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery

Comment: I didn't wrote the schema because it's optional parameter when we use data in JSON format [specification](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load.schema)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example on their [loading data page](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery).  Note the project id is located in two places, both jobData and destinationTable.  This might be the cause of the missing parameter error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "destinationTable" must be inside "load" object:

```
{
   "configuration": {
       "load": {
           "sourceFormat": "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"
           "destinationTable": {
               "projectId": "some-id",
               "datasetId": "dataset-id",
               "tableId": "cards"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

It can be seen in [Loading Data Into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery) page.